# How to use iterator in nested arraylist

Tags: java, iterator, nested-lists

I am trying to build an NFA with a special purpose of searching, which is totally different from regex. The State has following format

```
class State implements List{
//GLOBAL DATA

static int depth;

//STATE VALUES
String stateName;
ArrayList<String> label = new ArrayList<>(); //Label for states

//LINKS TO OTHER STATES
boolean finalState;
ArrayList<State> nextState ; // Link with multiple next states

State preState;             // previous state

public State()
{

    stateName = "";
    finalState = true;
    nextState = new ArrayList<>();

}
public void addlabel(String lbl)
{
    if(!this.label.contains(lbl))
        this.label.add(lbl);
}
public State(String state, String lbl)
{
    this.stateName = state;
    if(!this.label.contains(lbl))
       this.label.add(lbl);
    depth++;

}

public State(String state, String lbl, boolean fstate)
{

    this.stateName = state;
    this.label.add(lbl);
    this.finalState = fstate;

    this.nextState = new ArrayList<>();
}
void displayState()
{

    System.out.print(this.stateName+" --> ");
    for(Iterator<String> it = label.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
    {
        System.out.print(it.next()+" , ");
    }
    System.out.println("\nNo of States : "+State.depth);
}
```

Next, the NFA class is

```
public class NFA
{

static final String[] STATES= {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M"
                            ,"N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
State startState;
State currentState;
static int level;
public NFA()
{
    startState = new State();
    startState = null;
    currentState = new State();
    currentState = null;
    startState = currentState;
}

/**
 *
 * @param st
 */
NFA(State startstate)
{
    startState = new State();
    startState = startstate;
    currentState = new State();
    currentState = null;
    currentState = startState ; // To show that their is only one element in NFA
}

boolean insertState(State newState)
{

    newState.nextState = new ArrayList<>();
    if(currentState == null && startState == null ) //if empty NFA
    {
        newState.preState = null;
        startState = newState;
        currentState = newState;
        State.depth = 0;
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        if(!Exist(newState.stateName))//Exist is used to check for duplicates
        {

                newState.preState = currentState ;
                currentState.nextState.add(newState);
                currentState = newState;
                State.depth++;
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

boolean insertState(State newState, String label)
{
        newState.label.add(label);
        newState.nextState = null;
        newState.preState = null;

    if(currentState == null && startState == null)
    {
        startState = newState;
        currentState = newState;
        State.depth = 0;
       return true; 
    }
    else 
    {
        if(!Exist(newState.stateName))
        {

                newState.preState = currentState;
                currentState.nextState.add(newState);
                currentState = newState;
                State.depth++;
                return true;

        }
        else
        {
            ///code goes here

        }
    }
    return false;
}

void markFinal(State s)
{
    s.finalState = true;
}
void unmarkFinal(State s)
{
    s.finalState = false;
}

boolean Exist(String s)
{
    State temp = startState;
    if(startState.stateName.equals(s))
        return true;
    Iterator<State> it = temp.nextState.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {

        Iterator<State> i  = it ;//startState.nextState.iterator();

           {
            while(i.hasNext())
            {

                if(i.next().stateName.equals(s))
                    return true;

            }


        }
        //else
          //  return false;
    }
    return false;
}
void displayNfa()
{
    State st = startState;
    if(startState == null && currentState == null)
    {
        System.out.println("The NFA is empty");
    }
    else
    {

        while(st != null)
        {
            if(!st.nextState.isEmpty())
            {
                Iterator<State> it = st.nextState.iterator();

                do
                {
                    st.displayState();
                    st = it.next();
                }while(it.hasNext());
            }
            else
            {
                st = null;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

/**
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    NFA l = new NFA();
    State s = new State("A11", "a",false);

    NFA ll = new NFA(s);
    s = new State("A111", "a",false);
    ll.insertState(s);
    ll.insertState(new State("A1","0"));
    ll.insertState(new State("A1111","0"));

    ll.displayNfa();
    int j = 1;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {

        int rand = (int) (Math.random()* 10);
        State st = new State(STATES[rand],String.valueOf(i), false);
        if(l.insertState(st))
        {
            System.out.println(j+" : " + STATES[rand]+" and "+String.valueOf(i)+ " inserted");
            j++;
        }
    }
        l.displayNfa();
        System.out.println("No of states inserted : "+ j--);
}
```

I want to do the following

1. This program always skip to display the last state i.e. if there are 10 states inserted, it will display only 9.
2. In exist() method , i used two iterator but i do not know why it is working
3. I have no idea how to perform searching for the existing class name, when dealing with iterators.
4. How should i keep track of current State, properly iterate through the nextState List, Label List in a depth first order.
5. How to insert unique States i.e. if State "A" is inserted once, it should not insert it again (The exist method is not working)

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using map structure instead of nested List

```
     State find(State state)
{
    LinkedList<State> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.push(null);
    State temp = null;
    State ptr = startState;
    if(ptr.stateName.equals(state.stateName))
        temp  = ptr;
    while(ptr != null && temp != ptr)
    {
        for(State nxtState :ptr.nextState.keySet())
        {
            if(state.stateName == null ? nxtState.stateName == null :     state.stateName.equals(nxtState.stateName))
            {
                return nxtState;
                //break;
            }
            else
            {
                list.push(nxtState);
            }
        }
        ptr = list.pop();
    }
    return temp;
}
boolean insertState(State stateA,  String label, State stateB)
{

    ArrayList<String> lbls = new ArrayList<>();
    lbls.add(label);
    stateA = find(stateA);
    if(stateA != null)
    {
        stateB.nextState = new HashMap<>();
        stateB.preState.put(stateA,lbls);
        stateA.nextState.put(stateB, lbls);
        currentState = stateB;
        State.depth++ ;
        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println("State does not exist : somthing wrong with state input or NFA creation");
        return false;
    }

}

void displayNfa()
{
    LinkedList<State> stateForIteration = new LinkedList<>();
    State ptr = startState;
    if(ptr == null)
    {
        System.out.println("The NFA is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print(ptr);

        while(ptr!= null)
        {
            if(!ptr.nextState.isEmpty())
            {
                for(State key : ptr.nextState.keySet())
                {
                  System.out.print(key+ "  ");
                   stateForIteration.push(key);
                   }
                ptr = stateForIteration.pop();
            }
            else
            {
                ptr = null;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}

/**
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
void insertRule(String[] rule)
{
for(int i = 0; i < rule.length - 2; i=i+2)
{
    this.insertState(new State(rule[i]), rule[i+1], new State(rule[i+2]));
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    State strtState = new State("A");
    NFA ll = new NFA(strtState);
    String[][] data = {
        {"A","0","B","1","C","1","D","1","C0"},
        {"A","0","B","1","C","1","D","1","C0"},
        {"A","0","C","1","D","1","C0"},
        {"A","0","D","1","C0"}
        //{"A","0","B","1","C","1","D","1","C0"},
      };

    ll.insertRule(data[0]);
    ll.insertRule(data[1]);
    ll.insertRule(data[2]);
    ll.insertRule(data[3]);

    ll.displayNfa();
}
```

The "State" class is

```
class State implements List{

static int depth;

String stateName;

//LINKS TO OTHER STATES
Map<State, ArrayList<String>> nextState ; // to link with multiple states
Map<State, ArrayList<String>> preState;             // previous state

public State()
{
    stateName = "";
    nextState = new HashMap<>();
    preState = new HashMap<>();
}
public State(String StName)
{        
    stateName = StName;
    nextState = new HashMap<>();
    preState = new HashMap<>();
}

@Override 
public String toString()
{
    String temp = " "+this.stateName;
    for(State key : this.nextState.keySet())
    {
        temp = (temp + "  ");
        for(String lbl : this.nextState.get(key))
        {
            temp = (temp + lbl);
        }
            temp = temp + "  "+key.stateName+ "\n";       
    } 
    return temp;

}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (obj instanceof State) 
    {
        //id comparison
        State st = (State)obj;

        if(!(this.stateName == null) && (!(st.stateName == null)))
            return (this.stateName.equals(st.stateName));
    }
    return false;
}
```

out put is

```
A  0  D
   0  C
   0  B
D  1  C0
   C  1  D
   B  1  C
   C  1  D
   D  1  C0
```